# Python codegeneration from OpenAPI spcification

Tags: python, openapi

Having an OpenAPI 3 specification, I'd like to generate stub code from it, defining the DTOs/serializers/deserializers, webframework-agnostic. The plan is to use this generated code not only for the client, but for the server as well. Marshmallow dataclasses models would be great, or maybe Pydantic. Any tool already existing to solve this?

Comment: Check out the list at https://openapi.tools/#server and https://openapi.tools/#sdk.

Comment: Thanks @Helen - I've checked those first, hence the question, I guess the list is far from being complete. Right now we are experimenting with `swagger-marshmallow-codegen` btw.